# change link text of dynamically appearing links jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a dynamic HTML of a link. The link is appearing with every content coming from database. Its functionality is same as facebook like link. When user clicks the link the text should change to 'Liked'. The link with which I am dealing is with class 'likeLink'. Here is my HTML

```
while($fetch = mysql_fetch_array($selectResult))
                {
                ?>
                        <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2 well" style="background: #c8c8c8 url('ProfilePic/b10.jpg'); ">
                        <div class="col-md-2 thumbnail">
                            <img src="ProfilePic\<?php echo $fetch['ProfilePic']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $fetch['ProfilePic']; ?>">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-3">
                        <p><a href="#"><b style="color:darkred;"><?php echo $fetch['Name']; ?></b></a></p>
                        <span><?php echo $fetch['PostContent']; ?></span></br>
                        <a href="#" class="likeLink" postAttrVal="<?php echo $fetch['PostId'];?>"><i class="fa fa-thumbs-o-up">Like</i></a>


                        <span ><?php echo $fetch['Visibilty']; ?></span>
                        <span ><?php echo $fetch['CreateDate']; ?></span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <?php
                }
```

my jquery code is:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('body').on('click','.likeLink', function(){
        $.ajax({
            type:"post",
            url:"likescript.php",
            dataType:"json",
            data:{
                "postid" : $(this).attr('postAttrVal')
            },
            success:function(data){
                if(data == true){
                    $(this).html('<i class="fa fa-thumbs-o-up">Liked</i>');
                }
                else{
                    alert('Something Went Wrong');
                }

            },
            error: function(data){
                console.log(data);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Any idea about how it can be achieved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to store the reference of `this` in a variable, As in success callback method `this` doesn't refer to element which invoked the event.

```
$('body').on('click','.likeLink', function(){

    //Store it in a variable
    var _this = $(this);

    $.ajax({
        success:function(data){
            if(data == true){
                //Use stored variable
                _this.html('<i class="fa fa-thumbs-o-up">Liked</i>');
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

first saving the instance of this object :

```
 $('body').on('click','.likeLink', function(){  
      var currentClickedElement= $(this);
    ////other codes
    )}
```

then add context property in ajax call to set the ajax context

```
 context:this,
```

Then any of the below approach should work: 
One approach:

```
success:function(data){
                if(data == true){

 // this will add the new Id.                  
  $(currentClickedElement).html('<i class="fa fa-thumbs-o-up">Liked</i>');

                }
                else{
                    alert('Something Went Wrong');
                }

            }
```

Second Approach:

```
               if(data == true){
var $firstI =                        $(currentClickedElement).find('i').eq(0);
$firstI.Text('Liked');

                    }
                    else{
                        alert('Something Went Wrong');
                    }

                }
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case, `$(this)` isn't what you think it is when you do `$(this).html('<i class="fa fa-thumbs-o-up">Liked</i>');`

You're within the context of the `success` callback function. Before you call your ajax function, set `var $this = $(this)` so you're in the context of the element. Then you can use `$this` in your callback.